# rails - how to specify given number of top unique results returned in a given join query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to pull a query that will pull the top 20 unique "members" based on their top individual "report scores". the problem is that if the top member's 2nd best report score is also in the top 20, then the query only returns 19 members

```
top_members  = Member.all(:joins=>[:reports],  :conditions => ["score > 0"],:order      => ["score DESC"],:limit      => 20).uniq
```

what do i need to do get the query to keep going till i have 20 members?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're grabbing 20 results from the database and then discarding the duplicates when calling `uniq()`. Instead you can select distinct results from the database, something like:

```
top_members = Member.all(:joins=>[:reports], 
  :conditions => ["score > 0"],
  :order => ["score DESC"], 
  :limit => 20, 
  :select => 'DISTINCT members.*').uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to do this in two stages:

1) `id_list = Member.all(:select => 'distinct id', :conditions => ["score > 0"],:order => ["score DESC"],:limit => 20`

2) `top_members = Member.find(id_list, :joins=>[:reports])`.

Comment: hi chris. i started off using that approach - i'm pretty sure it'd work, but i was more looking for a one-step solution. thanks